# Azure Service Bus: Which message type?

Tags: c#, android, ios, azure, xamarin

I'm going to write an app under Xamarin for iPhone/Android/WindowsPhone that gets continuus data from a server and also sends back continuus data (~ every 10 seconds). I'm going to use Microsoft Azure. I've found that the service bus could help me. What type of messages (relay / brokered) should I use?

Imagine a service where you see the actual traffic situation. Every client sends it's anonymous traffic data to the server and it sends the state back to all receivers.

I've viewed [this tutorial too](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-relay-tutorial/), ist says

> The main difference between a WCF and a Service Bus service is that the > endpoint is exposed in the cloud instead of locally on your computer.

What does this mean? I need an endpoint locally on a smartphone. Is this usable?

I've read [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-messaging-overview/). I understand that for relayed messaging, both sender and receiver have to be online and it's a centralized (star-topology) communcation model. That would conver my needs. What confuses me is the word "relay". Does it mean, the messages are repeated somehow?

The brokered messages don't fit what I want becaus in my case it's irrelevant for the receiver if it is offline. The messages don't have to be stored.

Comment: Clarify your question after reading [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-messaging-overview/) article.

Comment: This article was why I posted the question. I have corrected my question and I hope this will help somebody to answer it.